# Не могу понять, как исправить ошибки. В Visual Studio ошибок нет, а в unity появляются

Tags: c#, unity3d

Помогите, пожалуйста, решить проблему, не знаю в чём ошибка:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class LevelObstacles : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform spawningObject;
    public Transform mainPersonPosition;
    private List<Transform> spawnedBrick = new List<Transform>();
    void Start()
    {
        StartCoroutine(SpawnCoroutine());//14-ая строчка кода
        StartCoroutine(DistroyCoroutine());//15-ая строчка кода
    }
    IEnumerator SpawnCoroutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Transform newSpawnObject = Instantiate(spawningObject, new Vector2(UnityEngine.Random.Range(-8, 8), mainPersonPosition.position.y + 6), Quaternion.identity);
            spawnedBrick.Add(newSpawnObject);//21-ая строчка кода
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(UnityEngine.Random.Range(2, 4));
        }
    }
    IEnumerator DistroyCoroutine()
    {
        while (true)
        {//28-ая строчка кода
            for (int i = 0; i <= spawnedBrick.Count;)
            {
                if (Math.Abs(spawnedBrick[i].position.y) - mainPersonPosition.position.y >= 10)
                {
                    Destroy(spawnedBrick[i]);
                    spawnedBrick.RemoveAt(i);
                    i++;
                }
            }
            yield return new WaitForSeconds(3);
        }
    }
}
```

Сам Visual Studio не нашёл ошибок, но в unity консоль выводит 2-ве ошибки, (на предупреждения не обращайте внимания):
[image]
[image]

На всякий случай я подписал строки кода, в которых есть ошибки.

Comment: А попробуй текст второй ошибки скопировать в переводчик. Разве не ясно будет, что требуется?

Comment: А первая, видимо, следствие второй. А вообще не гадать надо, а отладкой пользоваться частенько

Comment: В цикле i < spawnedBrick.Count (это как должно быть) (Вы используете несуществующий елемент массива)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В цикле `i < spawnedBrick.Count` (это как должно быть).

Вы же используете несуществующий элемент массива.